# CSA Approval for use in New York State sufficient?

Tags: code-compliance, venting

After extensive research, I'm interested in using a specific product for roof ventilation (http://www.ventilation-maximum.com/English/product-model303.html). All conditions for installation as per the manufacturer's installation requirements are satisfied.

The manufacturer is based in Canada and the description says it is CSA approved. Now my question is if that CSA approval is enough so that I can use it here in New York state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSA certified device will have the CSA mark on it (obviously).
But below the stylized CSA you may see some other letters, like this one has:
[image]
If your device is certified for use in the USA, then it will have the US in the lower-right corner or directly below.
No letters below means that it is only certified for use in Canada.
See [CSA Marks & Labels for North America](http://www.csagroup.org/about-csa-group/certification-marks-labels/csa-marks/) for further detail.

Answer (score 1):

CSA certification should be more than enough for a U.S. installation.

[CSA standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSA_Group) are typically higher and more rigorous than [UL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UL_(safety_organization)), the U.S. equivalent.